# How to use Filter Query to only get items if they match today's date?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm new to SharePoint and Power Automate / Flow. I have a SharePoint list with dates and I'd like to use "Get Items" in Power Automate to filter out the ones that aren't Today's Date (on any given date).

After I retrieve and filter the items, then I want to create an item in another SharePoint list using "Create Item."

I think I understand the second half, but I do not understand how to use Filter Query to only allow the items that match today's date (on any given day) to pass through.

I referenced this article trying to figure it out: https://baddaz.com/filtering-a-list-of-records-in-flow-based-on-todays-date-5a80292b366d

This is the expression I have in the Filter Query: formatDateTime(body(utcNow()),'MM/DD/YYYY')

I've attached a photo of my Flow so far.

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Filter-items-with-query-on-today-error/td-p/135723)

Comment: @GaneshSanap - Thank you. I'm still having trouble so I'm looking for more information online. I read a post that said you cannot use a calculated column in an OData Filter Query. Is that true? If so, that's most likely why I'm also having issues.

Comment: Yes, filters does not work with calculated columns. If your "Period Complete" column is calculated then it won't work, check [SharePoint REST API Limitation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-limitation)